# verifying generic types passed as arguments in mockito

Tags: java-8, mockito

I am trying to mock out a method on my callback module. It has two arguments

```
// callback module
    <R> void some_method(
            Class<R> resultType,
            Callback<R> callback
    ) throws IOException;
```

I have this in my test

```
private <R> void invoke(R response) {

    doAnswer(invocation -> {
        Callback<R> rh = invocation.getArgument(1);
        rh.onResponse(response);
        return null;
    })
            .when(callbackModule)
            .some_method(
                    ArgumentMatchers.<Class<R>>any(),
                    ArgumentMatchers.<Callback<R>>any());

}


invoke(new CallbackResponse())
```

I want to ensure/ verify that the args passed to `some_method` are of a certain type `R response`

IntelliJ complains at `ArgumentMatchers.<Class<R>>any()` and `ArgumentMatchers.<Callback<R>>any()` and wants to write it as `any() any()`

I am using Mockito on Java 8

Comment: you basically want to find out the *type* of `R` at runtime, you know that is not possible, right?

Comment: I want to ensure that those two arguments use `R`

Comment: sorry, it might be me, but I am not following you here